# How can I run a "DELETE FROM TABLE" with jdbc in spark 2.4?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using a code like this:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:url"))
```

I need to use a `DELETE FROM`.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE`/ `UPDATE` are not supported in Native Open source Spark.
There has been some effort in bringing this support as part of various Open source projects like [HUDI](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi), [Iceberg](https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg), [Delta](https://github.com/delta-io/delta).

Comment: this is the property to TRUNCATE a table [link]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16463[link], but doesnt work, maybe im using it bad ...

Comment: i dont want to use update and delete natively ... y just want to have the posibility to execute a QUERY like , truncate , update or delete